# Secure logout with PHP sessions

Tags: php, security, session

I have a login system based on PHP sessions. When user clicks on logout link, script calls `session_destroy()` function and the user logs out (session file on server with user data is deleted). When user just closes the browser, he logs out too (the cookie expired on close), but session file with user data is still kept on server.

So is there any vulnerability from the viewpoint of security? If so, what I have to do in order to prevent it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your security concerns? Depending on your answer, `session_destroy()` may be overkill, or the advice may be to avoid storing information in the session at all.

Comment: I'm anxious that the old session files, in some way, can be used by attacker to reset that session.

Comment: You need to rely on 21st century web browsers which should clean session cookies when browser is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use [session.gc properties](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) to remove old session files.